# Django: Unable to get user's groups from LDAP user

Tags: django, openldap, django-auth-ldap

My Django ( Django 1.11) project is using  django-auth-ldap 1.2  as authentication backed.

I have no problem to authenticate any user agents LDAP database  using:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
```

and in this case, any user from any group can login to the site.

I want to allow only user from 'group1' to be able to access the website.
I used the code listed below

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
  @user_passes_test(
            lambda u: hasattr(u, 'ldap_user') and 'group1' in u.ldap_user.group_names,
            login_url='/accounts/login/')
    def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template('main/index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

This is code is not working and user will never pass the test.
According to the model documents [django-auth-ldap Document](http://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/1.2.x/users.html#direct-attribute-access) I can use ldap_user.group_names to get group names of a user.

Here is my ldap settings from settings.py:

```
import os
import django



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',)

import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType


AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://mydomain.com"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "mypass"

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=ou_org_unit,dc=mydomain,dc=com",
ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=ou_org_unit,cn=group1,cn=group2,dc=mydomain,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
)

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType()

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
```

My question is:
Why I am not able to authenticate any user with this code?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the [AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#auth-ldap-require-group) setting if you want to restrict logins to a single group.

You will also likely want to use [AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#auth-ldap-mirror-groups) in order to have all of your LDAP groups automatically loaded into your Django database.

As a bonus, you can include multiple groups in the `AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP` setting, by using the `LDAPGroupQuery` class. For example (taken from [the documentation](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/groups.html#limiting-access)):

```
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPGroupQuery

AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = (
    (
        LDAPGroupQuery("cn=enabled,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com") |
        LDAPGroupQuery("cn=also_enabled,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com")
    ) &
    ~LDAPGroupQuery("cn=disabled,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com")
)
```